# Android: Update ImageView Background while Behind other ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-animation, android-framelayout

I'm building an app where I want to swipe images as though they were photos on a stack. In other words, if I swipe the top image I want it to animate moving in the direction of the swipe and have the next image underneath it visible the whole time. To accomplish this, I'm using a `FrameLayout` and two `ImageView` containers. I'm just alternating which one is on top. Meanwhile, as soon as a swipe occurs, the next image is loaded into the `ImageView` at the back using `setBackground(drawable)`. My problem is that the `ImageView` at the back doesn't update it's image until I call `bringToFront()` on it, which means that as the top `ImageView` is animating, the image underneath is incorrect until  the animation completes, at which point it abruptly changes to the correct image. I've tried calling `invalidate()` on the rear `ImageView` after `setBackground(drawable)` but this doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas on how I can get the image to update while it's behind?

UPDATE: Turns out I'm just not very on it today. I was updating the wrong `ImageView` and because the image loading was being done off the network, there was just enough lag to make me think it was happening after the animation completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you wanna do something like an **Image Slider**.

There are great libraries existing for this purpose, this one for example:

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

---

If you don't wanna use this, here are some tips:

- Images on `ImageView`s are set with `setImageDrawable(Drawable)`
- When your animation starts, set the new Image to your `ImageView` behind and slide the visible one away.
- When the visible `ImageView`has slided away, set it's visibility to `GONE`and move it behind the second `ImageView`

Do this for every time a new image is loaded.

This should actually work.

Comment: I'll have to look into AndroidImageSlider, but meanwhile those steps are essentially exactly what I'm doing. I changed from `setBackground(drawable)` to `setImageDrawable(drawable)` but it made no difference. The other two steps are what I'm doing. I think the problem is that `ImageView` doesn't update it's image unless it's z position is at the top, or something like that anyway. I just can't figure out how to force it to redraw before it's on top.

Comment: I feel sheepish... It turns out I was updating the wrong `ImageView` so that's what was causing the problem. I'd up vote you for being right but I don't have enough reputation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need a "ViewPager"

> https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

It has all the necessary handles to accommodate "N" number of images - also supports multiple swipe animations - default handlers - efficient memory management - prefetching - you are all in for a feast with this !!

Just make sure you get the "ImageView" in the layout of the "pages" you wish to develop on the "ViewPager".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had been thinking about doing a ViewPager but didn't want that many fragment transactions. Thanks again!

Comment: @Nick any reason you don't want Fragment transactions ? it is only going to make your app better with independent lifecycle and pre-fetch is going to happen automatically when user swipes an image